Start inkscape as separate processes by default
I'm not crazy, it's possible - run inkscape --app-id-tag <RANDOM-ID> and inkscape starts as a new process separate from the others. But is it possible to make this a default behavior? I've been losing hour(s) recovering inkscape crashes after importing large PDF, because if one inkscape instance crashed it took all of them down with it.
I couldn't find any documentation how to separate inkscape instances and came across this flag by pure luck. Why does it be so by default?

Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Sorry but this is not a graphic design question, so I'm voting to close it as off topic. Perhaps something you could ask on SuperUser or StackOverflow.

Get Sandboxie https://sandboxie-plus.com Create several sandboxies which all can have an installed Inkscape or run the existing one with private data. Sandboxie doesn't prevent programs to read files, but all writes happen only in the sanbox. A crashed instance doesn't spoil the run-time data of the others. Windows Cut&Paste happens from a sandbox to other.
